# Linear Velocity is slow(libGDX)

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm having a problem with slow and limited linear velocity in libGDX,
don't know why, but it's limited to `1.416f`. I'm using:
`world.step(1, 0, 0);`

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    viewport = new ScreenViewport(camera);
    viewport.setScreenPosition((int) camera.position.x, (int) camera.position.y);
```

Please help,
staticcasty

Comment: Sounds like this might be interesting for you: http://blog.xoppa.com/pixels

Comment: i wonder if your problem was solved, if yes could you please turn your question as resolved by choosing a correct answer, or writing your own answer thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is gone. I found a solution for this.
I had to just scale everything by 40, despite the fact that **box2d limits velocity to 2 Newtons**.
It means that I had to scale in "Desktop Launcher" the *config.width/40, config.height/40* and scale everything that is drawing by sprite batch - it was a problem, despite that I have multiple classes with drawing functions.

Anyway, thank you for your help.

Greetings,
Olaw

Answer (score 0):

Don't put **velocityIterations** and **positionIterations** to 0

```
int velocityIterations = 8;
int positionIterations = 3;
world.step(1, velocityIterations , positionIterations);
```

if that doesn't solve your problem, leave a comment

good luck !

Comment: It still doesn't work. I tried other numbers, but still the velocity is 2.0.

Comment: Also, I use this to add linear velocity: body.setLinearVelocity(speed,0) when the body goes right